# function requires non-empty input: How to circumvent error in this case?

Tags: python, loops, call, keyerror, empty-list

My code consists of several function running some tests. Let's say f1 produces a list of names "listnames", which is then used as input for f2 for further analysis.

List names looks like this:

```
0    ('stock1', 'stock2')
1     ('stock3', 'stock4')
2     ('stock5', 'stock6')
Name: listnames, dtype: object
```

and I call each of these elements in a loop, for instance like:

```
for i in test:
   print(i[0]) # or respectively print(i[1])
```

Now what could happen is that listnames could

```
a) has only one row 
b) be empty
```

the problem is now when I try to call the elements of the tuple within the list:

```
a) 
test = listnames[0]
('stock1', 'stock2')

for i in test:
   print(i[0]) # or respectively print(i[1])
```

gives me only a letter only from 'stock1' and 'stock2'

```
b) doesn't give anything back, which leads to a KeyError: b.
```

What is best practice to wrap a code:

1. to avoid the issue above
2. to prevent a loop that runs x-times to stop but just to "jump" over that step and start from new?

Comment: In the second loop you're iterating over the elements of the `test` tuple, so it makes no sense to `print(i[0])` unless you want to access its individual characters. Just `print(i)` instead.

Comment: that's the point, I cannot control how many rows the list has and as long as count(row) > 1, i would need i[0] to access the first element for instance; however, if count(row) = 1, it only takes some letters, and if count(row) = 0, I get a KeyError (because apparently I calling something empty for further use).